# JS works only after console.log

Tags: javascript, php, console, console.log

I created a back button which returns to the previous page form and to keep values in `<select>`, I pass the values in session and then through JS select the appropriate value.

The code works.

The problem is some time ago the code stopped working. I reran the code - nothing changes. Just to check, before the actual change occurs, I put `console.log()` to see if the values get passed in, and after that the code magically started to work.

Edit: after I reverted the code to its initial state, everything seems to work as expected.

Does anyone know what happens,  and how can I ensure it will not happen again?

Answer (score 0):

You should provide code examples, for example in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)